# Manage globally installed npm CLI tools on multiple devices

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I save most of my settings/dotfiles on cloud, but am struggling to sync up npm CLIs (e.g. `gulp`, `yo`, etc.) between devices.

Is there a recommended way of managing npm CLI tools across multiple machines?
Is it possible to create a package.json for this use case?

As a temporary and very manual solution, I could only come up with dumping the list of CLIs.
This is less than ideal, as this approach cannot uninstall existing packages.

```
# Save the list of globally installed npm packages
ls `npm root -g` > list_of_npm_tools

# On other machine, install by checking up the list
for i in `cat list_of_npm_tools`; do npm install -g $i; done
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can handle this with a network/cloud store containing your global `node_modules` and a PATH variable on each computer that references the folder you sync. That way the modules are shared from your single source of truth, and npm can just check your path for the shared globals.

Comment: It could work, I would then need to update [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#global) so that `npm update -g` updates packages appropriately. I was hoping if there was something like [emacs cask](http://cask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/usage.html) for npm CLIs.